# XMPP errors in custom protocols

Tags: xmpp

I am building an application heavily relying on XMPP. Apart from using existing protocols I also use custom protocols. I try to comply as possible with standards in defining those protocols and wonder about how to return errors consistently.
[XEP-0086](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0086.html) gives me all I need but the XEP is marked as deprecated. Is there a XEP that supersedes it, are there guidelines on how to respond with errors or one builds custom errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stanza errors are described in [XMPP: Core section 8.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-8.3), and [section 8.3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-8.3.2) talks about how and where you should place custom error info.